# while creating a promo code in the Play Console for our app, we got the error: "1 or more of the words you’ve entered can’t be used in promo codes"

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application, promotion-code

We already created other promo codes in the Play Console for our app. This time, when entering the string for the Custom Code, we got this message: "1 or more of the words you’ve entered can’t be used in promo codes".
I looked on the google store instructions, but there is no information about any forbidden words (mind you, we are a health app, some words can be mistankenly considered "unappropriate"; in this case, it is the name of a drug which contains the particule "gyno").
Anybody found any information on this?

Tried composing words, but still not accepting the particule.
In the end, changed the custom code entirely.

Comment: Share the promo codes names

Comment: as mentionned in the text, words containing the particule "GYNO". Examples tried: GYNO, GYNOTEST, TESTGYNO

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be from the word "GYNO" and could be from the word `Test` because sometime Google do not approve words like "free, test, demo, uncomplete, beta ...etc"

> Custom codes cannot contain offensive or inappropriate words or phrases.
> [source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495#zippy=%2Cstep-set-up-a-promotion-in-play-console)

I recommend using "Gyn" instead of "Gyno" and "exam" instead of "test"
so use `GynExam` as a name for the promo code

Comment: Thank you for the source. No list though, just a vague definition. The fact that "gyno" is considered "offensive or inappropriate" is what is actually offensive, for a whole profession and topic.

Comment: PS: as mentionned is the words tested, the problem comes from "gyno"